# Do data extracts need to be timestamped?

Tags: python, version-control, data-science, pipeline

Should I timestamp my data extracts?

A few collegues an me work together on a python server to solve a data science related problem. I wrote a few functions to extract my data from my source data base and save it to the python server for further processing. Now I'm struggling with whether I should save the extract with a timestamp, the result being that every time I start my pipeline another extract is saved or omit the timestamp and overwrite the old extract. I read alot about data not needing the same kind of version control as code does and I don't really want to clutter the server with multiple, vastly redundant data extracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **save the extract with a timestamp, the result being that every time I start my pipeline another extract is saved or omit the timestamp and overwrite the old extract.**

**Is the change of a feature over time important to your data science related problem?**

- Do you have any metrics which could tell a story if measured over time?
- Perhaps you can store the delta since last data pull instead of redundant features (feature engineer on a different table).

Just a couple of thoughts. Good luck :)

Comment: Features don't really change over time as I only extract records that have reached the end of the associated process. Each record is timestamped with a date of creation and completion. The only change over time would be freshly completed instances joining the dataframe. I guess, I could easily reconstruct the old status by filtering the date columns. Guess I got my answer, thanks mate